# NSDictionary initWithContentsOfFile: getting only empty Objects

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im saving an NSDictionary like this:

```
 NSDictionary *menuList = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:xmlParser.items];
 NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *directory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:MENU_LIST_NAME];
 NSString *filePath = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent: fileName];
 [menuList writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]
```

[image]

as seen, the dictionary is filled with Data, as it should be.

I read from the file like this:

```
NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *directory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:MENU_LIST_NAME];
NSString *filePath = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
NSDictionary *theMenu = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

however here I only get empty objects:

[image]

I´m just cant find a solution about this. please help. Thank you.
edit: The File Content (it seems to be written correctly)

```
<dict>
<key>left</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>id</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>level</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>link</key>
        <string>
        LoginActivity</string>
        <key>linkType</key>
        <string>internal</string>
        <key>state</key>
        <string>ANY</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>


        Login</string>
        <key>visible</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
            etc....
```

Comment: What does the file look like?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the dictionary is actually empty, and that this isn't just a debugger bug?

Comment: Please post the file.

Comment: I know the interface isn't showing anything, but can you try write code to access some inner content and see what you get? I've had problems where the content was fine but Xcode somehow failed to display it.

Comment: I´m afraid that´s exactly what happened. Cost me half a day. I will double check it again.

Comment: yep, exactly as you said it. That is terrible. If you want you can write an answer I´ll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects were not empty. Xcode debugger just somehow showed them empty. If somebody has the same problem, consider this and it might save you lots of time.

Comment: This was my problem, probably just saved me a ton of time.  Love that XCode.

Answer (score 3):

Your file seems not to be the properly plist.
From the documentation:

> initWithContentsOfFile: Initializes a newly allocated dictionary using
>   the keys and values found in a file at a given path.
>
> The dictionary representation in the file identified by path **must
>   contain only property list objects** (NSString, NSData, NSDate,
>   NSNumber, NSArray, or NSDictionary objects). For more details, see
>   Property List Programming Guide. The objects contained by this
>   dictionary are immutable, even if the dictionary is mutable.

Comment: I just see I have a BOOL in my Dictionary...that might be it.

Comment: it still doesnt work even if I just let the BOOL away. I have an NSDictionary filled with NSString s. To my understanding its conform to the documentation.

Comment: I just found out that if I only save one single NSString in the plist instead of a whole Dictionary, it still returns only empty objects.

Comment: No, BOOL in a plist is perfectly fine and the file looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try the command line

```
plutil path-to-your-file
```

Maybe it will tell you something wrong with the file.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might that somehow you are not copying the values into this new dictionary but pointers, so when trying to retrieve the contents the references are lost. Try using
`NSDictionary *menuList = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: xmlParser.items;` and make sure that *items* on xmlParser are declared as a *(nonatomic, retain)* property.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue using initWithContentsOfFile to read a plist from /Library/Preferences - a mismatch between your target's bundle identifier and the reverse domain name in the plist can cause a nil return too.